# Loading Dataset for two different sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am experiencing a problem with loading of my work order page.

When I load my page I am just passing the id of the work order WO.aspx?inspectionid=12345

Now on computer 1 I am loading
WO.aspx?inspectionid=1

Now on computer 2 I am loading
WO.aspx?inspectionid=2

To reproduce my issue I click the respective inspection on each separate computer at the exact same time (well as close as I can to a manual simultaneous click)

Now when I debug my LoadWorkOrder function in my code, it calls a stored procedure and populates a Dataset.  Now before the first call completes and loads up the rest of the page, I see that my second call is already hitting my LoadWorkOrder function, thus causing one of the pages to error out.

So my question is, is there a way to properly handle multiple calls on the same function.  Is this a threading related issue?  I am not quite sure even what to google to help solve my issue.

---

```
    private void LoadWorkOrder()
    {

        //Bizlogic.cInspectionsBizLogic.GetInspection(dstInspection, mintInspectionID);
        dstInspection = new cInspectionsDST();
        Bizlogic.cInspectionsBizLogic.GetInspection(ref objDataAdapterForUpdate, dstInspection, mintInspectionID);



        if (dstInspection != null && dstInspection.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Bizlogic.cSchedulerDST dstItem = new cSchedulerDST();
            dstItem = Bizlogic.cSchedulerBizLogic.GetScheduleItemForInspectionID(mintInspectionID);
            LoadInspectionAddressHeader();
```

I don't see anything special here, its just a simple loading of a dataset.  The error message I do seem to be getting "There is no row at position 0".  Within my cInspectionsDST.Designer.cs file.  These DataSets are created within Visual Studio I've inherited so changing those is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: Show us the code you've got issue with.

Comment: What is the actual error please?

Comment: Are you instantiating a new class every time the page is requested? i.e. the class where LoadWorkOrder is a member.

Comment: I'm thinking that the first dataset is not completely populated before the second one takes over and gets populated.  Because as I was debugging and viewing the dataset in Visual Studio, one of them was completely empty...

Comment: This is in my code behind of the page WO.aspx.  I am calling LoadWorkOrder() on Page_Load when it is not a postback.  I am getting the mInspectionId from the page parameter that I am passing in.

Comment: I've made dstInspection  a static variable, so this might be the culprit.

Comment: You are running the calls concurrently on 2 computers, can I check where the web server (IIS) is running please? And do both calls to `inspectionid=1` and `inspectionid=2` both work independently!?

Comment: @foop, As has already been asked, what is the error message produced?

Comment: The error message I do seem to be getting "There is no row at position 0". Within my cInspectionsDST.Designer.cs file.

Comment: @richaux Both work independently.  I can reproduce this on my dev server and on my local machine.

Comment: @foop, thanks. As you say, it looks like your static variable may indeed be the cause, the initial page's values being trampled by the second request. Certainly worth ruling this out.

Comment: @richaux it was the static variables

Answer (score 0):

dstInspection was a static variable once I removed that and reworked the code I no longer had this issue

Comment: of course it would work when you remove the static variable. think why...do you understand what static means and how it works? :) you shouldn't use this for multi threaded applications unless you have a reason to (generally you do not).

Comment: I inherited this code actually...and upon trying to not disturb the existing baseline of code and adding my own work on top of it it was something I had overlooked.